# How to send images to URL type to FireStore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I upload image to firestore sending photo path to database. But I need to send URL type for list in app. How can I convert photo paths to URL? 
[image: dbimg]

```
Future uploadFile() async {
if (_photo == null) return;
final fileName = (_photo!.path);
final destination = 'files/$fileName';

try {
  final ref =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('feedPhotos/');
  await ref.putFile(_photo!);
} catch (e) {
  print('error occured');
}
```

}

```
Tweet tweet = Tweet(
id: id,
text: _tweetText,
image: _photo.toString(),
authorId: postID.toString(),
likes: 0,
retweets: 0,
timestamp: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now(),
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is , on upload image to firebase, get image link and save it to your database e.g

```
final storageReference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images/myuniquefilename");

    await storageReference.putFile(myfile);
    String imageUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
// imageUrl is your download link

//save to firestores
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("images")
        .doc(docId)
        .set({
"url":imageUrl
...
```

Comment: as u see at screenshot file format is photo path but I want to this need to be URL format

Comment: you get that from getDownloadURL,